# Was the Elder Wand really that great?

Tags: harry-potter, wandlore, deathly-hallows

Just from the fact the Dumbledore defeated it when Grindlewald was using it makes me wonder if it was really unbeatable. Unless of course he beat him non-magically. But that could just be hype.

Answer (score 20):

**The Elder Wand was very powerful, but by no means unbeatable.**

It wasn’t just Grindelwald and Dumbledore; there’s mention of “hundreds” of defeats of the Elder Wand from some of Dumbledore’s notes:

> What must strike any intelligent witch or wizard on studying the so-called history of the Elder Wand is that every man who claims to have owned it has insisted that it is “unbeatable”, when the known facts of its passage through many owners’ hands demonstrate that not only has it been beaten hundreds of times, but that it also attracts trouble as Grumble the Grubby Goat attracted flies.
>
> — Albus Dumbledore, commentary on *The Tales of Beedle the Bard*

It has performed remarkably powerful magic – for example, repairing Harry’s old wand, a feat beyond most ordinary wands – but it is not infalliable.

Comment: its one of those things, were, you have an amazing weapon that enhances all of your spells and your already better then everyone else so you seem quite powerful, as in the case with grindelwald, and so why bother studying more magic when at 20ish he has the most powerful wand in existence. Dumbledore on the other hand continue to study magic religiously i believe theres a 10ish year gap from when they part till Dumbledore fights him, and by then Dumbledore is by far the superior wizard with or without the ElderWand.

Comment: basicly the elderwand makes you cocky.

Comment: Reminds me of that story of the survival test where those with machine guns and flamethrowers lose out to those armed with just knives and their wits.

Comment: What is it with Dumbledore family and goats?

Comment: Just for clarification is it clear whether or not Dumbledore is referring to defeats while someone was wielding the wand because especially in the legend of the Deathly Hallows the owner is defeated through trickery when they weren't expecting an attack thereby defeating/killing them when they were not currently using the wand? I question whether anyone in true possession of the wand was defeated while wielding the elder wand.